# Turtles moving into a circular formation

Tags: geometry, netlogo, turtle-graphics

I have two breeds of *turtle(A)* & *turtle(B)*:

- Turtle(A) move about the world randomly.
- When `turtle(A)` runs into a `turtle(B)` I would like the `turtle(B)` to move into a radius around a coordinate, thus hopefully making a circle.

Any help/hints?

Answer (score 1):

That specification is a bit incomplete, but this may get you started:

```
globals [lst]
breed [taggers tagger]
breed [taggeds tagged]
taggeds-own [caught?]


to setup
  ca
  set lst []
  ask n-of 50 patches [sprout-taggeds 1 [set caught? false]]
  ask n-of 5 patches [sprout-taggers 1]
end

to move ;;turtle proc
  ask taggeds [
    if not caught? [
      move-to one-of neighbors
      ]
  ]
end

to tag ;;tagger proc
  let candidates taggeds-on neighbors
  if any? candidates [
    let captured one-of candidates
    ask captured [set caught? true]
    set lst lput captured lst
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles [move]
  ask taggers [tag]
  layout-circle lst 5  ;;aribtary radius of 5
end
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. I was wondering if there was a way to put the circle not at the center of the world, i.e. without using the 'layout-circle' command.

Comment: Sure, you can divide a circle into as many parts as you have turtles to layout, put the center anywhere you want, choose a radius, and work through your list of turtles placing one at each circle coordinate.